# Django: where can I find the template that renders the fields of the admin page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I want to change the shape of some fields showed in the admin site.

I found that the template that manage everything is `change_form.html` with `fieldset.html` but I cannot find where the fields are actually transformed in html.

Basically I want to change the field of the foreign key adding a link to another page.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,
Giovanni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML for a given field is handled by its widget in the render function.  If you want to customize the look of a field you could create a custom widget which has the additional HTML you need in the render.

You can check out the render some of the built in widgets in [django/forms/widgets.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py) (links to the Django trunk).

Answer (score 0):

In fieldset.html, the code {{ field.field }} renders the field's HTML representation. to achieve what you want, you'll probably need to define your own widget. you can take a look at admin's widgets.py